# java classes and loop for inserting names

Tags: java

I'm facing some problems with java classes.

Here is a class I defined

```
public class Condutor {
    private String name;

    public Condutor() {
        name = ""; 
    }

    public Condutor(String aName) {
        this.name = aName;
    }

    public void setName(String aName) {
        name = aName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

and on the main I have this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Condutor[] names = new Condutor[10];
    Condutor name = new Condutor();
    String aName = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        aName = "Mike" + i;

        name = new Condutor(aName);
        names[i] = name;      
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++) {
        System.out.println(names[i]);
    }

}
```

This works as expected printing this:
    Mike0
    Mike1
    null
    null
    null
    null
    null
    null
    null
    null

Maintaining the same class but changing

```
name = new Condutor(aName);
names[i] = name;
```

by

```
name.setName(aName);
names[i] = name;
System.out.println("------");
System.out.println(names[i]);
System.out.println("------");
```

it prints

```
------
Mike0
------
------
Mike1
------
Mike1
Mike1
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
```

I can see that in the loop everything works as expected but the names array stores in the first two positions the last input.

Why does this happens?
Should't it store exactly as in the loop?

regards,

Favolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create new objects in the second case too:

```
name = new Condutor(); //add this line to make sure you create new object in every iteration
name.setName(aName);
names[i] = name;
System.out.println("------");
System.out.println(names[i]);
System.out.println("------");
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand and doing what you said solved the problem

Answer (score 3):

This happens because only one Condutor is ever created and it is added at both the [0] and [1] locations.

For i = 1 when you change the name it is reflected at both [0] and [1] location

Answer (score 1):

Because in the second you are not creating a new instance of Condutor. You are using the same instance each time.

```
Condutor[] names = new Condutor[10];
Condutor name = new Condutor(); // this is the one that is being used.
```

Answer (score 1):

In your 1st version, you are creating a separate instance in each iteration of the first loop. This way, every "condutor" keeps his individual name.

In the 2nd version however, you are assigning and therefore reusing the same Condutor instance (the one created in line 2 of main()) over and over in each iteration, only changing the name of this one object. Thus, when printing the results, you only see the name of this single object, how it was set last.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
names[i] = name;
```

you're **not copying** the object under `name`, but you're simply copying a **reference** to it into `names[i]`. Note that after the change you never create any instances of `Conductor` other than the one created on the second line of `main`. Note also that `name` always refers to the same instance you created in the second line of `main`. It follows that when you do

```
name.setName(aName);
```

you repeatedly set the name of the same object. You also **copy** the reference (not the object) to the first and second elements of the array:

```
names[i] = name;
```

Eventually, there is only one `Conductor` which has had its name updated **twice** (in the first loop) and reference to which is stored in `name`, `names[0]` and `names[1]`. This explains the output.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand. You made it simple to understand.